# Wix Directory Confusion?

Tags: wix

So I have my installer working, however the directory ID's have my confused.

Right now I have:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MainFolder" />
              <Directory Id="APPFOLDER" Name="Utility" >
               </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

My Component Group (for all my files to get moved) referenced "Utility", However it creates a Folder in Program Files called "Utility" and Not MainFolder/Utility.

How do I make it go to Program Files/Mainfolder/Utility instead of Just Program Files/Utility

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current Directory structure is set like this (MainFolder and Utility are under programFiles)

```
SourceDir  
  ProgramFiles  
     MainFolder  
     Utility
```

Change the Directory structure in your fragment like the code below it will create a structure like this (Utility is now under Mainfolder) Notice how the Directory element of the INSTALLFOLDER now doesn't have an end tag "/>"

```
SourceDir  
  ProgramFiles  
     MainFolder  
        Utility
```

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MainFolder" >
              <Directory Id="APPFOLDER" Name="Utility" >
              </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I was looking at your heat  harvest question, but you deleted it  ;)

Comment: Actually ironically that was an accident lol but essentially I cannot figure out a way to register multiple .dll's using heat or if it's even possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734754/how-can-i-exclude-files-from-being-harvested-with-heat-wix-3-5  look at Yan Sklyarenko answer.

Comment: AH I see. Quick question: Since Im harvesting the heat information on my computer im using a folder reference for my computer and not the actual computer/directory it's going to be installed on.....does this matter?

Comment: Nope, it's will be relatif to the installation process